# Error in plsql code - ORA 06550

Tags: sql, oracle, cursor

```
DECLARE  
   CURSOR cur  
   IS  
      SELECT   dm.fash unit, h1.groupin, '01' startin, SUM (h1.weight)  
          FROM tab1 t1 INNER JOIN tab2 h1 ON t1.ALTER = h1.unit  
               INNER JOIN unit dm ON t1.col1 = dm.unit  
         WHERE t1.col1 IN (SELECT col1  
                             FROM tab1  
                            WHERE sw = 1)  
           AND h1.eve = 'Al'  
           AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1  
                             FROM tab2  
                            WHERE unit = t1.col1)  
      GROUP BY dm.fash, h1.groupin;  


BEGIN  
   FOR rec_in IN cur  
   LOOP  
      INSERT      /*+append*/INTO targ  
                  (unit, groupin, startin,  
                   weight, length, height  
                  )  
           VALUES (rec_in.unit, rec_c1.groupin, rec_c1.startin,  
                   rec_c1.weight, 4, 5  
                  );  
   END LOOP;  

   COMMIT;  
END;  
/
```

This might be an easy thing . But i am unable to find the reason.

When I run the above query i am getting an error saying the component 'WEIGHT' must be declared ( the field weight in the values field rec_c1.weight)
The table Targ has the columns - UNIT,GROUPIN,STARTIN,WEIGHT,LENGTH,HEIGHT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know Oracle, but I guess you need to name the SUM column, i.e.
`SUM (h1.weight) weight`

But do you really need a cursor? Can't you do a insert with select?

```
INSERT INTO targ  
                  (unit, groupin, startin,  
                   weight, length, height  
                  )
SELECT   dm.fash unit, h1.groupin, '01' startin, SUM (h1.weight)  
          FROM tab1 t1 INNER JOIN tab2 h1 ON t1.ALTER = h1.unit  
               INNER JOIN unit dm ON t1.col1 = dm.unit  
         WHERE t1.col1 IN (SELECT col1  
                             FROM tab1  
                            WHERE sw = 1)  
           AND h1.eve = 'Al'  
           AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1  
                             FROM tab2  
                            WHERE unit = t1.col1)  
      GROUP BY dm.fash, h1.groupin;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @jarlh . Yes that resolved the issue - Naming the SUM column.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your cursor loop with qualifying the columns from your cursor. You have specified the loop identifier as rec_in but have typed rec_c1 for groupin, startin and weight:

```
BEGIN  
FOR rec_in IN cur  
LOOP  
   INSERT      /*+append*/INTO targ  
               (unit, groupin, startin,  
                weight, length, height  
               )  
        VALUES (rec_in.unit, rec_c1.groupin, rec_c1.startin,  
                rec_c1.weight, 4, 5  
               );  
END LOOP;  

COMMIT;  
END;
```

/

This has to be rec_in just as with unit:

```
BEGIN  
FOR rec_in IN cur  
LOOP  
   INSERT      /*+append*/INTO targ  
               (unit, groupin, startin,  
                weight, length, height  
               )  
        VALUES (rec_in.unit, rec_in.groupin, rec_in.startin,  
                rec_in.weight, 4, 5  
               );  
END LOOP;  

COMMIT;  
END;
```

/

Comment: Sorry . I corrected that and tried , but its giving the same error.